# Lookup excel return min value if no match found

Tags: excel, match, lookup

If number from first coulmn is found in the second column, it should return that number.
If number from first coulmn is not found in the secound column, it should return closest possible min value

[image]

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use vlookup() like this, BUT you need to sort the values:

[image]

Comment: In ExcelO365, one could use spilling down with `=VLOOKUP(A1:A4,SORT(B:B,1,1),1,TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

In **C1** enter the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(B:B<=A1,B:B))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

**NOTE:**
Sorting is not required.
Array entry is not required if you are using Excel 365.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($B$1:$B$12<=A1)*$B$1:$B$12))`

It works on Excel 2007 or higher, no need of array *entered* formula and no need of sorting.

Comment: No need of array *entered* formula =). A technicality but `SUMPRODUCT` is an array function. There is no gain other than the more explicit ranges you are using. +

Comment: That's true, indeed. :)